# Run script with timeout once per session (but you could reload page and go to another page)

Tags: javascript, session, cookies

I've got a simple script, that I need to run only once per session of user. But in this session he could refresh page, or go to another page on one site.

My code now looks like this, but if user refresh page (in less then 10 seconds) or go to another page - script will never run :(

```
var visited = sessionStorage.getItem('visit');
if (visited == null || document.location.href == sessionStorage.getItem('lastPage')) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
    alert('Hello World')
        }, 10000
  )
    sessionStorage.setItem('visit', 1);
  };
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/zavtraleto/pen/GdRpRZ

I think it's something with cookies, maybe

Comment: why 10 seconds timeout?

Comment: @Vineesh it will be a popup form with a small survey about interface, so user must spend a time on a website (timeout could become longer)

Comment: You want to display the popup only once in a page? or once in whole website navigation?

Comment: @Vineesh once in whole website navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it using cookie, so if everyone interested:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    function checkCookie() {
        var user = getCookie("username");
        if (user != "") {
            alert("Welcome again " + user);
        } else {
            user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
            if (user != "" && user != null) {
                setCookie("username", user, 365);
            }
        }
    }

    getCookie('user_first_visited') || setCookie('user_first_visited', Date.now());

    if (!getCookie('user_popup_triggerred')) {
        var loopDetect = setInterval(function(){
            var TimePast = (Date.now() - getCookie('user_first_visited')) / 1000;
            if( TimePast > 5){
                if (localStorage.getItem('surveyOnce') !== 'true') {
            (function() { 
                alert('Hello World!')
                }
              )();
              localStorage.setItem('surveyOnce','true');
              };
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```